# How to add new key value pair when loop through array of objects in lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

for example:
from:

```
var a = [{
  num: '1,3,4'
},{
  num: '3,2,6'
}]
```

to:

```
var b = [{
  num: '1,3,4',
  arr: [1,3,4]
},{
  num: '3,2,6',
  arr: [3,2,6]
}]
```

it's better to use lodash one-liner

Comment: Have you tried something? Or you prefer _"do what i want"_. Any example code what you do?

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner with the built-in `Array.map`:

```js
var a = [{ num: '1,3,4' }, { num: '3,2,6' }];

var b = a.map(({ num }) => ({ num, arr: num.split(',').map(Number) }));

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to load `lodash` when it can easily be done with a one-liner of plain JavaScript. Like this:

```js
var a = [{
  num: '1,3,4'
}, {
  num: '3,2,6'
}];

a.map(obj => Object.assign(obj, {arr: obj.num.split(",").map(Number)}))

console.log(a);
```